# Pass data of the ApplicationUser without sensitive data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my application, I have several **entities** which contain one or many `ApplicationUser` When I pass this data via **JSON** to my frontend, it always contains *sensitive data* (e.g. the password hash). Because of this, a user can see this data of another user, and that is **really critical**.

Now to my question: I'm wondering was a nice and *clean* solution, to handle this is.

The only thing I have in mind for this would be, to have a `ViewModel` for the user with data, every other user can see without any problems and then "transform" the `ApplicationUser` to this `UserViewModel` whenever I want to get data and transform it back everytime I send data. For this, a ViewModel for every single entity which implements the `ApplicationUser` will be needed. This seems like a huge thing to do and maybe you can help me on finding a nicer solution for this.

Comment: It's sensitive data, not sensible. And to introduce Data Transfer Objects (which is how viewmodels are called in an API context) _is_ the sensible thing to do. To map between entity models and DTOs relatively painfree, you can use tools like AutoMapper.

Comment: Thanks for that input!